# Is it possible to connect my phone via bluetooth and then call through the computer?

Tags: bluetooth, phone, smartphone

I am running Ubuntu 18.04LTS with Unity and I'd like to connect my phone via bluetooth to my computer and when someone calls, be able to pickup the call using the computer's microphone and headsets. Is this possible ?

I looked into GSConnect and other solutions but I did not find one which allows me to pickup the call from the computer.

If someone has a solution that requires the phone to be plugged-in via USB, I'm good with that too.

Answer (score 0):

It may work with [**scrcpy**](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) over TCP/IP (Display and control your Android device) and the tool [**sndcpy**](https://github.com/rom1v/sndcpy) (Android audio forwarding (scrcpy, but for audio)). I have not yet time to test it myself, though.
A discussion regarding forwarding audio and scrcpy you can find on the [Github page of scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/14), other suggestions was to use scrcpy and use bluetooth for audio.